# Lightning web component Toast Notification not working in SF Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created an LWC component with just one button and on click of that button I am trying to show notification using ShowToastEvent, This is working fine on desktop but not working in SF mobile app.

HTML File

```
</div>
```

Js File

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class ToastNotificationOnMobile extends LightningElement {

```
handleClick(){
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Welcome',
                variant: 'success',
                mode : 'dismissable'
        }),
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

It is because [toast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) is not available for ***Mobile App***

---

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation), it says that toast is just available for ***Lightning Experience (one container)*** only

[image]

---

Comparatively, when you check the docs of **[pill](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill/example)**, it is available for all containers - ***Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App, Standalone Lightning App***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Toast doesn't work in the Salesforce Mobile App container so the only way is to make a custom toast check out this link incase you need

https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/03/16/custom-toast-component-in-lightning-web-components/

Events belonging to the force namespace are not supported in Salesforce Mobile App container and
If you see the aura code for toast you will see toast originates from force namespace, so my guess is that in the backend they didn't redo the code

var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components